# Does a Rod of the Pact Keeper add its bonus to a Pact of the Blade Hexblade's pact weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, class-feature, warlock

This is perhaps more of a RAI question as opposed to RAW, but if a [Hexblade Warlock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#TheHexblade) with Pact of the Blade can add his Charisma bonus instead of Strength or Dexterity to the attack rolls of his pact weapon, shouldn't a Rod of the Pact Keeper add its bonus to that too?

I realize the Rod says you gain the bonus to spell attack rolls, and using the pact blade isn't really a spell attack, but that same warlock would have a higher bonus to hit with a cantrip than their pact weapon. It just seems like an oversight.

Comment: @SeriousBri Gentle reminder to [not answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/48759).

Answer (score 9):

### No it does not

The Rod says

> While holding this rod, you gain a bonus to spell attack rolls and to the saving throw DCs of **your warlock spells**.

Weapon attacks are not warlock spells. The rod's intended function is to improve the warlock's spellcasting prowess.

Answer (score 4):

#### No.

As already noted in the question and in this [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/208441/63061), the bonuses granted by this magic rod regard spell attacks rolls and saving throw DCs of warlock's spell.

Note that if your table allows multiclassing and you have levels in another class with a spellcasting feature, these bonuses do not apply to the rolls and DCs related to this class.

#### When a magic item grants bonus to weapon attacks and/or damage, it states so.

There are magic items which are not weapons that grant such kind of bonus. A not comprehensive list includes:

- [Bracers of archery](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4593-bracers-of-archery)

> [...] you gain a +2 bonus to damage rolls on ranged attacks made with such weapons.

- [Oil of sharpness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4688-oil-of-sharpness)

> [...] For 1 hour, the coated item is magical and has a +3 bonus to attack and damage rolls.